# Why does Apache CXF - Jax RS allows 'GET' requests to take up 'HEAD' requests?

Tags: java, rest, get, jax-rs, cxf

I am using Apache CXF Jax-RS to implement RESTfull services. I have implemented a GET call as shown below:

```
@GET
@Path("getSomething")
@Produces("application/xml")
public String getSomething() {
    return null;
}
```

This is working fine for me but a bug is raised on this after the tester was able to use this service operation with a HEAD request (POST and other calls fail). I did a little research and found that HEAD request is similar to GET, with the only difference being that it doesn't return a body. So i have a few questions regarding this.

1) Why does JAX RS allow operations annotated with @GET to receive HEAD requests while it does have a separate @HEAD annotation available ?

2) Could this cause any kind of problem in my application

3) If i have to disallow @GET operations to take @HEAD operations, i could i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It is defined in [JAX-RS 1.0](https://jsr311.java.net//nonav/releases/1.0/spec/spec3.html#x3-290003.3.5):

> `HEAD` and `OPTIONS` requests receive additional automated support. On receipt of a `HEAD` request an implementation MUST either:
>
> 1. Call a method annotated with a request method designator for `HEAD` or, if none present,
> 2. Call a method annotated with a request method designator for `GET` and discard any returned entity.
>
> Note that option 2 may result in reduced performance where entity creation is significant.

2) No, because your method has to be safe, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer):

> The GET method is a safe method (or nullipotent), meaning that calling it produces no side-effects. In other words, retrieving or accessing a record does not change it.

3) You could annotate another method with `HEAD`, see [Jersey 2.22 User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2051):

> By default the JAX-RS runtime will automatically support the methods `HEAD` and `OPTIONS`, if not explicitly implemented.